# Elasticsearch - Date mapping issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I'm currently having a strange issue and I can't find anything related to it.
I have an elasticsearch cluster for my production environment with 3 nodes.
Recently I created a single-node cluster for my staging environment.
My issue is that I created a brand new index to test things on staging, and the data was getting persisted successfully, the issue is that the dynamic mapping its recognizing my "time" field as a **long** which is a UNIX date on milliseconds format and is working ok on production.

So I tried to add the mapping manually to be recognized as a date:

```
PUT /my-index/
 {
  "mappings": {
   "properties" : {
    "time" : {
     "type" : "date"
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

but in those cases when I try to send data to be persisted I get the following error on the http response:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [time] cannot be changed from type [date] to [long]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [time] cannot be changed from type [date] to [long]"},"status":400}
```

I tried also using the exact same mappings I was using on my production env and I get the same results.

My production ELK stack is version 7.6 and the staging one I built is 7.12. Also tried with a 7.10 version with the same results. I read about the breaking changes and I didn't found anything that could be causing this.

[UPDATE]

This is how a documents looks like on my production env:

```
{
  "time" : 1615145429958,
  "properties" : {
    "actor_status" : null,
    "seller_name" : null,
    "listing_mls_number" : null,
    "listing_customer" : "CB Canada",
    "seller_status" : null,
    "utm_source" : null,
    "lib_version" : null,
    "browser_version" : "82",
    "actor_pxs_id" : null,
    "seller_id" : null,
    "listing_pxs_id" : null,
    "initial_referrer" : "$direct",
    "currency" : null,
    "listing_types" : null,
    "media_language" : null,
    "listing_title" : null,
    "listing_country" : null,
    "utm_term" : null,
    "search_engine" : null,
    "listing_state" : null,
    "seller_pxc_id" : null,
    "listing_postcode" : null,
    "listing_id" : [
      "pxc:5fb6b57f23d1bc2c25d9cca0"
    ],
    "os" : "Windows",
    "screen_height" : 900,
    "device" : null,
    "listing_pxc_id" : "5fb6b57f23d1bc2c25d9cca0",
    "seller_pxp_id" : null,
    "time" : 1615145429958,
    "mp_keyword" : null,
    "city" : "Offenbach",
    "actor_email" : null,
    "listing_price_usd" : null,
    "initial_referring_domain" : "$direct",
    "country" : "DE",
    "actor_id" : null,
    "app" : "B2C-Portals",
    "page_type" : "Property Details",
    "screen_width" : 1600,
    "mp_country_code" : null,
    "utm_medium" : null,
    "browser" : "Firefox",
    "actor_pxc_id" : null,
    "listing_status" : null,
    "actor_pxp_id" : null,
    "listing_address" : null,
    "area_unit" : null,
    "utm_campaign" : null,
    "seller_pxs_id" : null,
    "actor_name" : null,
    "insert_id" : null,
    "listing_pxp_id" : null,
    "mp_processing_time_ms" : null,
    "distinct_id" : null,
    "region" : "Hesse",
    "seller_email" : null,
    "mp_lib" : null,
    "listing_city" : null,
    "media_type" : "Photo",
    "language" : null
  },
  "event" : "View Property Media"
}
```

If I do the following steps I'm able to ingest data but any query with range will throw error:

1. Create the index
2. Ingest the first doc to let the dynamic mapping do the work.

but if I add the mapping manually ingest stops working as I show above

Thanks in advance!!

**[UPDATE2] - SOLUTION**

**If is useful for anyone!**
I found that the issue wasn't related directly to the index mappings, but to the index types, I was using a custon type on staging and I was using _doc on production, this was causing the issue.

Comment: Can you also share the data that you are indexing?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question, to add that information

Comment: @LorenzoZuluaga I think there is more than 1 document stored. And the previously saved documents might have different format. ElasticSearch doesnt allow this .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not the case, since I'm creating an index from 0, to start ingesting documents, but the dynamic mappings its taking my time field as a long, but if I change manually this mappings the data ingest stop working because of the error I showed about changing the date type into long type